# How to set percentages of traffic for each variation in Google Experiments?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there the option to manually set percentages of traffic for each variation? How would you do it from the interface?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an option to manually set percentages of traffic for EACH variation. From the UI, you're only given the option to set the percentage of traffic to WHOLE experiment e.g. 100%, 75%, 50%, 25%, 10%, 5%, and 1%.

Even after looking at the [Experiments API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/experiments), specifically the `trafficCoverage` property, which states that:

*A floating-point number between 0 and 1. Specifies the fraction of the traffic that participates in the experiment. Can be changed for a running experiment. This field may not be changed for an experiments whose status is ENDED.*